# Better way to represent the contents in a Debugging Context List?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2017, debuggervisualizer

In debug mode at least, is there a less fussy way to examine the contents of a populated List? I want to say it's a visualizer...? My Google-fu though is failing me this evening. Thanks.

[image]

I ended up downloading ML Collection Visualizer 2015-2017 here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181451/Visual-Studio-Collection-Visualizers

Comment: What do you mean by "Less fussy"?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25268/A-Generic-List-and-Dictionary-Debugger-Visualizer) work for you?

Comment: What do you mean what do I mean? :P I mean in such a way as I don't have to expand each node to view the contents, looking for a more spreadsheet-like visualization of the data, without yet going through the trouble of writing it somewhere.

Comment: Consider dumping the `List` output to a log file. Also consider implementing a container with a `.ToString()` method (the debugger lets you preview this).

Comment: @qxg Yes. Though it appears a bit old now...

Comment: @StevenMpls, So this issue has been resolved using the Visual Studio Collection Visualizers code sample, am I right? If so, not edit it in your issue, would you please share it as the answer and mark it later? So this case could be closed and it would help other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading ML Collection Visualizer 2015-2017 here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181451/Visual-Studio-Collection-Visualizers

While there are multiple legitimate answers, the above was what I was looking for. Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you sharing, you could mark it as the answer:)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) for your class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{count}, {flag}")]  
public sealed class MyClass   
{      
    public int count { get; set; }      
    public bool flag { get; set; }      
}
```

Comment: What if we can't change target class source?

Comment: ozcode is awesome even it's paid extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Backs' answer, you could override the `ToString()` method for the class to achieve the same effect.

```
public sealed class MyClass   
{      
    public int count { get; set; }      
    public bool flag { get; set; }      
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", count, flag);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do this then check out this SUPER CHARGED implementation: https://github.com/chillitom/ToStringBuilder

Comment: @JeremyThompson that looks very allocatey